# Delayed scrolling in chromium based browsers on Wayland

Tags: touchpad, chromium, 22.04, wayland

So I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop which now uses Wayland as a default and I noticed that the scrolling experience on chromium based browsers (like Brave) is horrible. It is not responsive and it is noticeably delayed. On Epiphany the scrolling is even weirder implemented with scrolling further than it is supposed to and on Firefox completely unusable because it is not smooth but in steps.

In other programs like TeXStudio or RStudio I do not have that problem at all. I've read that with Wayland allows the developers to implement their own scrolling behavior for their software. When I switch to xorg the scrolling behavior is snappy and direct again (but of course missing the nice Wayland feature in gnome 42).

Is there any extension that I can use as a workaround or is there maybe even a solution?

Thank you so much in advance!